# What is the best way to store a large global object in ASP.Net

Tags: .net, caching

My project requires me to create a database object (a custom class) containing a list of tables, each table containing a list of columns. The columns and tables object have specific properties not available in the database. For example label, max value, min value and so on.

All these custom properties are stored in database tables, which the user can modify. These properties will be used in various web forms.

My question: Is is wise to keep connecting to the database to find out these extended properties for each form, OR create a object (as explained above) and store all the tables, columns as lists and store that BIG object as an application variable.

I was also thinking to put the object in the cache and expire it whenever users make changes to the extended properties.

Can someone tell me if the best of the above 3 approaches or any other method to ensure best performance.

Thanks

**Edit**: This has to be a generic solution that should work on ANY database. So potentially, there could be a large number of tables (50-120) each having 10-30 columns

**Edit2**: I was also thinking of dynamically creating classes (like Entity framework does) and loading them using reflections.

Comment: how "big" are we talking? how many tables/columns/properties?

Comment: @alastair It could run into dozens of tables with 20-30 columns each.

Comment: And how many _rows_ are we talking about? Millions? Thousands? Less? More?

Comment: @Oded, this object will not store any table data. So as I mentioned, it I have 10 tables with 12 columns each, the DB object will have a List of Tables Object with 10 table objects and each Table object will have a List of Columns with 12 column objects. I'm only storing meta data of the database objects like column lables, max, min, defaults, textbox width, etc

Comment: @Oded, nope, just column and table definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are only caching meta data and no data, the amount to store is relatively small.

You have two options, as I see it:

- Store in the `Application` object, which is available to all sessions and will not expire (but will be around until the app pool is reset)
- Store in a `Cache` entry which allow you to set a future expiration or database dependency so you can refresh the data.

Since you say the user can change the data, a `Cache` with a database dependency looks like the right choice, though this is only supported directly with the [`SqlCacheDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx) class (so only applies to SQL Server).

A more generic approach would be a cache that expires and causes a polling of the DB on expiration.

Comment: Thanks Oded, is there any merit in dynamically creating classes (at runtime) with all the required properties and then loading them using reflections?

Comment: @Arun - If the use case requires it. I don't see how this helps you in your case.

Comment: @Oded, was only looking at reducing memory footprint, am just worried that this object could potentially be huge once the number of tables ans columns increase -http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/abff98e3-93fe-44fa-bfd4-fcfe297dbc43

Comment: @Arun - If you only have a single instance in memory, you should start worrying only if it starts taking gigs of memory. Meta data alone shouldn't do that.

Comment: And how about speed of accessing data? Is reading a value from a compiled object faster than reading an variable from a big list.

Comment: @Arun - I have no idea what you are talking about now. You cache a compiled object.

Comment: Thats ok Oded, I guess I'll have to experiment from now. Thanks for your help!